# HTML - Time Input with up to 100 minutes

Tags: html, timepicker

Is there any way to manipulate the html time input, so I can add up to 100 Minutes and 59 seconds?

Comment: You can use javascript or jquery???

Comment: What do you mean by “add up to 100 Minutes and 59 seconds”? Time input is for input of time, not adding. Do you mean setting the maximum time to 100:59?

Answer (score 0):

No. Time input is for time. Your clock is more than 60 minutes?
Another way is to write custom input field with JavaScript. Or add number input field and then with JavaScript calculate hours/minutes/seconds ...

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** After re-reading the original post, I'm pretty sure I'm answering the wrong question here. But I'll leave it in case someone else finds it useful.

If you're referring to `<input type="time">`, you can access and modify the value like a normal input element:

```js
var time = document.getElementById('time');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

function handleButtonClick() {
  var parts = time.value.split(':');
  var hour = parseInt(parts[0]);
  var minute = parseInt(parts[1]);

  hour += 1;
  minute += 7;

  // TODO: Need to validate the new time

  time.value = hour + ':' + minute;
}
button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick, false);
```

```html
<input id="time" type="time">
<button id="button">Process</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery for this:

```
function addMinutes(time, minsToAdd) {
  function D(J){ return (J<10? '0':'') + J;};
  var piece = time.split(':');
  var mins = piece[0]*60 + +piece[1] + +minsToAdd;

  return D(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + D(mins%60);  
} 
$("#add").click(function(){
    var time = $("#time").val();
    var new_time = addMinutes(time, '100');
    alert(new_time);
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XnhfU/69/)